# Load values from database to create a drop down menu based on the selection from previous dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

My problem is that I try to load a drop down based on selection from previous drop down. I'm loading the values from database. but when I use `$_get['emirate']` I'm not getting the value. It says the value is not set.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emirate") 
        or die(mysql_error()); 

    Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
    print"<tr><th><form method=get action='index.php'><select id=EMIRATE size=1><OPTION value=all>all</option>";
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    { 
        Print "<option value=". $info['em_name'] .">".$info['em_name']."</option>"; 
    }
    print"</select></form></th>";
    if(isset($_GET['EMIRATE'])){
        $name=$_GET['EMIRATE'];
        echo $name;

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT a_name FROM areas where em_id=(select em_id from emirate where em_name=\"".$name."\")") 
        or die(mysql_error());
        Print "<th><select name=AREAS size=1>";
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
        {
            Print "<option >".$info['a_name']."</option>";
        }
        print"</select></th>";
    }
```

Comment: it is not the answer of your question, but before you fix this problem, you should validate your html and validate it by w3c ....

Comment: `$_GET['EMIRATE']` will imply you're having a parameter called `EMIRATE` in your URL, so it would look something like `http://domain.com/yourScript?EMIRATE=someValue`. Is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem.

> I haven't put a **submit button** and hence my form wasn't getting
>   submitted. And hence I wasn't getting any value from $_GET.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Now I get the results smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

which method are you using on your form on the previous page, post or get?

you can replace $_GET with $_REQUEST which retrieves values from both post and get.

Comment: $_GET. The action is redirected to the same page as the code is written. Is that a problem?? i new to php..

Comment: i guess you havent got me..my both dropdown codes are in same file..:(

Comment: yes I got that, but i need to see both dropdowns or the entire file.

Comment: I see now, but like @donald123 said you're missing the name property on your select tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id=EMIRATE size=1><OPTION value=all>all</option>
```

Please fix the HTML.... you miss to set the **name** attribute for your select...

```
<select id="EMIRATE" size="1" name="EMIRATE">
    <option value="all">all</option>
    ....
```

Comment: i have done that before. but then i got an error sayin i dont have an index name 'EMIRATE'. so i changed my 'name' to 'id'